# Not all buttons showing up in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swing, jbutton

When I run my program using eclipse only one button shows up (top left corner) but when I use javac in terminal (most of the time) all buttons show up! It's really bugging me. Can anyone help? Thanks!
This is my constructor:

```
    public TicTacToe(){
    super("Farm Tic-Tac-Toe");
    setSize(450,750);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container cont = getContentPane();
    cont.setLayout(null);
    int newLine = 0;
    int lineCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        buttons[ i] = new JButton(blank);
        if(i == 3 || i == 6){
            newLine++;
            lineCount = 0;
        }
        buttons[ i].setBounds(lineCount*150,newLine*150,150,150);
        cont.add(buttons[ i]);
        buttons[ i].addActionListener(this);
        lineCount++;
    }
}
```

and here's the action  listener...

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        if(e.getSource()==buttons[ i]){
            if(turn%2==0){
                buttons[ i].setName("x");
                buttons[ i].setIcon(x);
                buttons[ i].removeActionListener(this);
            }
            else{
                buttons[ i].setName("o");
                buttons[ i].setIcon(o);
            }
            buttons[ i].removeActionListener(this);
        }
    }
    turn++;
    checkWin();
}
```

Please don't tell me too much about how my code design is bad because I am (not a beginner, but) not too good at Java.

Comment: I stopped reading after the `cont.setLayout(null);` line ... use a `LayoutManager` or you will get into trouble, as you just experienced the hard way

Comment: ...I'm reading a book that has this in it so um...

Comment: Then get rid of the book as it is clearly not a good Swing book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is really very simple...

The first one is the lack of a layout manager and the other is the order in which you are displaying your UI (as has already being stated)

[image]

```
public class SimpleTicTacToe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleTicTacToe();
    }

    public SimpleTicTacToe() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new GamePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GamePane extends JPanel {

        public GamePane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
            for (int index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
                add(new JButton());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Take the time to read through [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) to gain a grasp of the basics.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `setVisible(true)` *before* adding all of your components to the GUI, so it is not showing them all. Don't do this. Instead call `setVisible(true)` *after* all components have been added.

Also

- As has been suggested by many, don't use null layout, but instead learn about and use the layout managers.
- Yeah, get another book.

Comment: Hmm, should have read a bit further. Good catch, and not the first question with this resolution. Perhaps we should add this to the FAQ or the Info tab (in case anybody ever reads that before posting a question)

Comment: @Robin: sure add it, but I think we both agree that it will have little effect.

Comment: I am unsure on how to add it. To get it into the FAQ, it seems you need a question with a lot of views so that is not an option. Perhaps we can add a manually maintained FAQ in the Swing wiki, similar as for the Java tag wiki

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse GUI only renders buttons that are drawn in certain very specific ways. If your code does it differently (for example, with a Loop), Eclipse won't be able to draw it.

Also, use a `LayoutManager`, don't do things like `.setLayout(null)`

Comment: Re `"The Eclipse GUI..."` -- What is an "Eclipse GUI", and what does Eclipse have to do with any of the current issues here? It appears to me to be a pure and simple Swing issue and to have nothing to do with the IDE at all.

Comment: Are you really suggesting that when you use Eclipse as IDE, you cannot buttons to a panel in a loop. If that would be the case no self-respecting developer would want to touch that IDE

Comment: I was talking about the WYSIWYG editor, which is what he seems to be saying (because he said his program works with plain javac)

Comment: @durron597 I can't see why Eclipse's form editor should be doing anything unusual, it's designed to work within the Swing API, it's more likely that the user is doing something wrong, like calling `setVisible` on the main window before the content has being added and/or creating the UI outside of the EDT, which are classic problems that produce these symptoms